# Flag dialog tells me I've flagged a post I've never seen before

Tags: bug, status-completed, low-quality-posts, flag-dialog

I spotted a [spammy looking answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/248078/146318) (10k-only by now) and when I went to flag it, the flag dialog told me that I'd already flagged it as VLQ:

[image]

The thing is, I'd never seen this post before. And a look at the flag history in my user profile confirms that I haven't flagged a post since yesterday:

[image]

Certainly, well before the 2015-02-04 05:36:21Z time of Mr. Miracle's post.

I was able to reproduce this on SO from the VLQ review queue: when you're presented with an answer, click on `link` at the right side of the page, then click `flag`. You get the "you have already raised this type of flag" message on either the "it is not an answer" or "it is very low quality" options, I gather depending on the original flag that pushed the post into the VLQ queue.

Comment: Wonder if it got deleted as you opened the dialog? I flagged as spam and it got deleted at -6 which is what you have in the screen shot.

Comment: The post was automatically added to the VLQ queue, so it can't be redundantly flagged as such, I guess. The message doesn't realise that this is the cause of you not being able to use that flag and is wrong, of course.

Comment: @peterj: Nope. Keep reading my question to the end. I've reproduced it on SO and Arqade, where I can't [flag a post as NaA](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/204178/96918) even though I've just seen it.

Comment: I noticed but that's possibly a "feature" - if it's on the VLQ queue shouldn't you be recommending deletion instead? You'd otherwise just be flagging to put it back on the queue.

Comment: Here's [one on SO's VLQ queue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28313432/19465) at -1 as I write.

Comment: Ahh interesting, yes I get the same see what you mean now.

Comment: I've seen this in FP too. Haven't got a screenshot yet.

Comment: @Tim this makes sense, think it's worth posting as answer and the bug report be updated to ask for rewording of the message e.g. "this post is already identified as low quality".

Comment: While the message is wrong, it looks like a new feature to prevent "overflagging".

Comment: This is probably the result of [another bug being fixed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285272/known-redundant-flag-is-not-identified-in-flag-dialog/285280#285280).

Comment: @bummi actually that's a bad thing (even if it was true), since for every VLQ flag cast on a post, additional "Looks Good" vote is needed to remove the item from review. :/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This one was a regression.  Instead of checking if a particular user cast the flag it was only checking for the existence of any flag of that type.  This will be fixed very soon.