# Already raising NAA?

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags

I just made a [new account](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/8093/mooseman) to flag a "thank you" answer. But this is what I got when I clicked "flag":

[image]

This is a *brand new* account. What happened?

---

Update: this issue also occurred on Physics SE. It hasn't affected Stack Overflow or Lifehacks SE.

Comment: Possibly related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248080/flag-dialog-tells-me-ive-flagged-a-post-ive-never-seen-before

Comment: Also reported on MSO as ["you have already raised this type of flag" - no I haven't](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285317). It's a bug.

Comment: @PeterJ this one is better formulated

Comment: @MartijnPieters Should we link everything to here to deter redundancy?

Comment: @Mooseman: no, it's fine to track it here too. The bug appears on more than one site, but most people will look to their homesite Meta to report it or to find confirmation. It *does* look like the same issue PeterJ  linked to here on Meta.

Comment: @Jan it is, wasn't suggesting it was a dupe, but presumably the same underlying bug causing it.